# How to write KQL to convert CSV of key=value Pairs to Dictionary?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Say I had a Kusto table with a column that stores string-typed values which looked like this:

```
secure=false,ipVersion=6,http=HTTP/1.1,streaming=true,traceEnabled=true,debugEnabled=false
```

How could I write a KQL expression which converts this to a dynamic type value such as:

```
{'secure':'false','ipVersion':'6','http':'HTTP/1.1','streaming':'true','traceEnabled':'true','debugEnabled':'false'}
```

I have tried variations of `split`​ and `mv-apply`​ and `bag_pack()​` but I can never get it to fully work so I am looking for some expert advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the payload has a stable & prefedined schema, you could use `parse` and `pack()`:

```
print input = 'secure=false,ipVersion=6,http=HTTP/1.1,streaming=true,traceEnabled=true,debugEnabled=false'
| parse input with 'secure='secure',ipVersion='ipversion',http='http',streaming='streaming',traceEnabled='traceEnabled',debugEnabled='debugEnabled
| project output = pack('secure', secure, 'ipVersion', ipversion, 'http', http, 'streaming', streaming, 'traceEnabled', traceEnabled, 'debugEnabled', debugEnabled)
```

| output |
| --- |
| { "secure": "false", "ipVersion": "6", "http": "HTTP/1.1", "streaming": "true", "traceEnabled": "true", "debugEnabled": "false" } |

Alternatively, and less-efficiently, you could use `extract_all()`, `mv-apply` and and `make_bag()`:

```
print input = 'secure=false,ipVersion=6,http=HTTP/1.1,streaming=true,traceEnabled=true,debugEnabled=false'
| mv-apply pair = extract_all(@'(\w+)=([^,]+)', input) on (
    summarize output = make_bag(pack(tostring(pair[0]), pair[1]))
)
| project output
```

| output |
| --- |
| { "secure": "false", "ipVersion": "6", "http": "HTTP/1.1", "streaming": "true", "traceEnabled": "true", "debugEnabled": "false" } |

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional way based on [replace_regex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-regex-function)

We're replacing each `key=value` (and `,` or text end) with `"key":"value"` (and `,` or nothing).
The result, concatenated with `{` and `}`, could be then converted to dynamic.

```
print input = "secure=false,ipVersion=6,http=HTTP/1.1,streaming=true,traceEnabled=true,debugEnabled=false"
| project output = todynamic(strcat("{", replace_regex(input, "(.*?)=(.*?)(,|$)", @'"\1":"\2"\3'), "}"))
```

---

```
"output": {
    "secure": "false",
    "ipVersion": "6",
    "http": "HTTP/1.1",
    "streaming": "true",
    "traceEnabled": "true",
    "debugEnabled": "false"
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAzWOsQoCMRBEe8F/CItgIkE5BQshaCNYWojVgcTcekbOXNjbgKL%20u%20HEZorH8GYi%20cDCh5hYGAEdukRoLrbpUPt4ROp8G8xSX5mj2R0O%201kxLXTHhPbuQ22YEmom63Ab7LnB6kcqPKf6T3obDAdvEam9oWPRJv4Ncls9QzY5mZXOsoQXaEEYm2w8Edb4kP05LUBOJ2tl%20pT6PVK5uBlDWcAKyjmUi7HKpQ8o9QVbrhWA1AAAAA==)